# Converting Microsoft Visio 2007 .vsd file to xml workspace document (without the macro)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase, schema-architecture, geodatabase-xml

I was just editing my geodatabase schema in Microsoft Visio and noticed that it is the new 2007 version, rather than 2003 which had a handy export tool, therefore I downloaded the ESRIExportToXML macro, however when I use it, it comes up with the following error:

Run-time error'-2032465751 (86db08a9)':

The line of code which it breaks on is the following:

```
Set pAO = Application.Addons.Item("UML Background Add-on")
```

I have tried to fix the code or find other tools to export it to xml from visio but have virtually given up.  Therefore I was wondering if I could do something along the lines of export it to pdf then, using acrobat pro save as an xml (I have tried this but it created an invalid xml file), or convert it in excel?  Therefore is there a way round or alternative route for converting an .vsd file to xml file?

Comment: Just save the schema in the newer VXD format, which is actually XML.

Comment: is this the visio xml file type, I saved it as this, but then when I choose to import my schema into a geodatabase via an xml workspace document it doesn't include the visio xml file as an option.

Comment: Then you should change the question title to reflect what *kind* of xml you want. VXD **is** XML, just not the type you need.

Comment: changed the title...

Answer (score 1):

**Building Geodatabases with CASE Tools**

For UML/XMI compatibility, **Microsoft Visio 2007 Professional** can be used as a [CASE tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_software_engineering) for geodatabase schema design. Microsoft Visio 2007 Service Pack 2 is required to complete the process. For further information, see the article on Can Microsoft Visio 2007 be used as a CASE tool for geodatabase schema design?

When you're finished creating a geodatabase, you'll have generated feature datasets, feature classes, tables, and other items from the design with ArcCatalog.

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/product-documentation/view/productid/43/metaid/658

Comment: Yeah, I read that, but that annoyingly works on the premise that you download the aforemetioned macro and that it works, which it doesn't in mine, so this is why I have no way to export to xml.